# Plural form of a burn when possessive

Tags: nouns, grammatical-number

Is it correct to say "I want to take care of your burns" or "I have burns all over my body" for a burn (wound from getting burned).

Comment: it appears correct!

Comment: The source might be a single flame, but it may cause several areas of damage. 'Burning' causes a 'burn'. The skin itself begins to burn. And these can be plural.

Comment: 'I have a burn all over my back' sounds unidiomatic to me. I'd go with 'I have burns all over my back' even if  there aren't distinct patches.  Or rephrase.

Comment: What does this have to do with "possessive"?

Answer (score 1):

It *is* correct to use the plural "burns" for burns possessed by on individual patient both in idiomatic English and in medical literature as well.

Note language from https://chemm.nlm.nih.gov/burns.htm:

> Burn severity is dictated by:
>
> - Percent total body surface area (TBSA) involvement
>
>   - Burns >20-25% TBSA require IV fluid resuscitation
>   - Burns >30-40% TBSA may be fatal without treatment
>   - In adults: "Rule of Nines" is used as a rough indicator of % TBSA

Comment: But one would use the plural in say 'Chest wounds where no inner organs have been damaged'. This doesn't mean that 'Jack has a chest wound' is unacceptable or that 'Jack has chest wounds' is always the better choice.

Answer (score 0):

There are many different kinds of event that can result in a *burn*,
and there are many ways to classify them.

In talking about the results on a patient, whether under medical care or not,
either singular or plural may be used, at the speaker's discretion. Everything
depends on how the speaker wants the situation described.

After all, the speaker knows more than the addressee does about the facts,
or they wouldn't be talking about them.

For instance, it's possible that a bad sunburn could cover one's whole back,
and therefore be referred to in the singular.

- *Bill got a first-degree burn down his back at the pool yesterday.*

Contrariwise, there may be several  distinct burned areas in a small part of the body
like one arm, that occurred in separate events, and therefore may be referred
to in the plural.

- *Bill got first-degree burns on his arm from fireworks yesterday.*